# Cucumber --glue does not find step definitions when running using executable jar in cmd

Tags: java, cmd, cucumber

I used intelliJidea, maven to create this pure java project and when I run main class It generates report and works fine.
This is the main class.

```
 public static String[] defaultOptions = {
           "--glue", "com.test",
            "classpath:",
           "--plugin", "pretty",
            "--plugin", "html:cucumber.html"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Stream<String> cucumberOptions = Stream.concat(Stream.of(defaultOptions), Stream.of(args));
        Main.main(cucumberOptions.toArray(String[]::new));
    }
```

Then I created a single jar(myJar.jar) of my cucumber project using maven. I wanted to run it in command line.
So I executed this command inside the folder which contains jar.

```
java -jar myJar.jar --glue *
java -jar myJar.jar --glue com.test
java -jar myJar.jar --glue com/test
```

I tried all of these options.
When I tried first command, that generates report without executing any test.
Second and third command, does not identify step definitions. (all step definitions are in com/test)

Please help me to identify issue here.

Comment: You probably didn't make the jar file in the right way.

Comment: I removed some unwanted dependencies from pom.xml. Now new error was there. It says  "Suppressed: io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: By default Cucumber scans the entire classpath for step definitions.
However the resource 'jar:file:/C:/Users/Desktop/demo/dist/myJar.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/maven-compiler-plugin-3.8.1.jar!/' is located in a nested jar. This typically happens when trying to run Cucumber inside a Spring Boot Executable Jar.
Cucumber currently doesn't support classpath scanning in nested jars."

Comment: Where are your feature stored?

Comment: What exactly did you do? And what does the layout of your jar file look like? You can use `tree` to visualize it in text. You may have to remove a lot of things to make it more readable.